# How to professionally draw a custom control for better cpu/memory usage?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

I am currently developping a personal theme that I entend to use in my application. I have a question regarding the custom controls I'm creating and their CPU/Memory Usage!

### Code

I'll show you an example of my custom label control.

**Constructor**

This is where I set the DoubleBuffer mechanism and styles/properties.

```
public DarkLabel()
{
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    ForeColor = Helpers.TextColor;
    BackColor = Helpers.LightDarkColor;
    _textAlign = TextAlignements.Left;
}
```

**OnPaint override**

This is where I do the drawing of the custom control.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Helpers.SetHighQuality(g);

    // Background
    g.Clear(BackColor);

    // Text and Image
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
    {
        // Image but no Text
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && _image != null)
        {
            g.DrawImage(_image, Width / 2 - _image.Width / 2, Height / 2 - _image.Height / 2);
        }
        // Image and Text
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) && _image != null)
        {
            SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(Text, Font);
            if (_textAlign == TextAlignements.Left)
            {
                g.DrawImage(_image, 2, Height / 2 - _image.Height / 2);
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, b, _image.Width + 5, Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawImage(_image, Width - Image.Width - 2, Height / 2 - _image.Height / 2);
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, b, Width - _image.Width - textSize.Width - 7, Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2);
            }
        }
        // Text
        else
        {
            SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString(Text, Font);
            if (_textAlign == TextAlignements.Left)
            {
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, b, 2, Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, b, Width - textSize.Width - 2, Height / 2 - textSize.Height / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

## Result

This custom label gives me exactly what I need, a text and an image (if it exists) next to it, whether its aligned Left or Right.

## Questions

What is the most professional way to create custom controls like these? Do professionals (like `DevExpress`, `Telerik`) use the same technique or is there something better to improve (or at least avoid) CPU/Memory usage?

Comment: Just a tiny detail, but text on controls ought to be rendered with TextRenderer (better scalability..)